# iTextSharp Phrase string doubling on pdf output

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I'm very new to using iTextSharp to generate a pdf.  I have the following code that places text from my form to the pdf output.  I am using a Phrase & ColumnText to position the text from a particular textbox onto my pdf output.  I've tied a variable as well as the text property of the textbox as the Phrase string, but it places two sets of the same text on top of each other(screenshot).
[image]

```
string oldFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "invoice.pdf";
string newFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "NewInvoice.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSize(1);
Document doc = new Document(size);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, true);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
cb.BeginText();
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, invoiceDate, 480, 603, 0);
cb.EndText();
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(textBox1.Text);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(phrase, 65, 375, 540, 300, 16, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.Go();
doc.Close();
fs.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
Process.Start(newFile);
```

If I assign a string (string whatever = "some text here...";) and place this in the Phrase string(..new Phrase(whatever); it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I'm the original developer of iText.

I hope you'll believe me when I say you should use a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` combination instead of a `Document`/`PdfWriter` combination. This is documented in [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book. You may not see any difference on the outside, but the PDF feel be so much better on the inside.

It's kind of strange that you're adding text at absolute positions. Wouldn't it be better to use a template that has some AcroForm fields on the locations where text is needed? Your code will be so much easier to maintain.

I also see that you're using `HELVETICA` as font with the parameter for embedding equal to true. Surely you know that the `embedded` parameter will be ignored for `HELVETICA` which is one of the Standard Type 1 fonts.

Finally for your question: I don't think your code is adding the phrase twice. I think you've been experimenting and that you're adding a new phrase over a phrase that already exists in the original file "invoice.pdf". If you're 100% that this isn't the case, then you should share your PDF so that I (or somebody else at iText) can inspect it.

Comment: thanks for responding.  From what I have learned by experimenting and from the web in general, in order to have a pdf that has controls(to accept text) I would need to purchase a piece of software(adobe professional, etc) to do so, which isn't an option for me.  So I created one in Illustrator.  So I went the route that positions everything.  I checked the "invoice.pdf" saved in my default directory and it doens't have this text already in it, so it couldn't be copying over it.  I don't understand why it works when I assign text to it directly.  sting whatever = "whatever";

Comment: Well, Illustator isn't free either, is it? You could easily create a form using Open Office. Open Office can be downloaded for free. You can find an example that explains how to create a PDF with such controls in section 6.3.5 of the chapter I mentioned.

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean when you say "I don't understand why it works when I assign text to it directly." Directly to what? Directly how?

Comment: I use what I have on hand at the office.  I didn't realize that open office could create a form with controls...thanks.  I guess I'll have to go that route in order to fix this issue.

Comment: You don't HAVE to go that route, but it will save you time when you need to maintain your application. If you do it your way, you'll have to change your code every time the document changes (something moves half an inch up; another thing half an inch down, etc...). With an AcroForm, this has no effect whatsoever on your code as long as you keep using the same field names.

Comment: Just before the line Phrase phrase = new Phrase(textBox1.Text); string Comments = "Something here..."; then Phrase phrase = new Phrase(Comments); and it works.  but if I use textBox1.text or a variable that holds the text property(from TextChanged event) I get the doubling.

Comment: That's strange. I don't have an explanation for that.